# Need java regex to get a particular output

Tags: java, regex, string

This is my code.

```
String parsedValue = "(1234)";
if(!parsedValue.equals("")){
    parsedValue = parsedValue.replaceAll("\\(*\\)", "");//I can just change the regex but still need to use replaceAll method.
}
System.out.println(parsedValue);
```

I am getting the output : `(1234`
My expected output is : `1234`
Basically I want to get rid of parenthesis at both ends.
I cannot use any way other than replaceAll method. That part of the code is not under my control. I can just change the regex.
Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: FYI: `\\(*\\)` means "zero or more `(`s, followed by one `)`". The only thing in your string which matches that is the `)` at the end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You only need to target characters anywhere, use only a character class:

```
parsedValue.replaceAll("[()]", "");
```

Alternatively, if you only want to target characters that are at the start or at the end, use anchors (`^` and `$`) and an alternation (`|`):

```
parsedValue.replaceAll("^\\(+|\\)+$", "");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Dint knew it was so easy.

Comment: @Casimir can you please explain or give useful link to understand your first regex expression

Comment: @rupesh_padhye: any basic tutorials about regex should suffice. `[...]` is a character class and means "one of these characters", so `[()]` means "an opening or a closing round bracket". Then `replaceAll` will search all the string for round brackets and replace each of them with an empty string.